# Can I use the Google Maps API to display a custom map?

Tags: google-maps

And by custom map I mean custom map tiles, as in, mapping another planet. I've looked all around but can't see to find any resources pointing how to do this on Google's or any website.

I know it's possible because I've seen it done before on a website, but unfortunately the website that has the link to THAT site is down so I can't get to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [API](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#ImageMapTypes).  This might help you by loading own images as an overlay:

> Image Map Types
>
> Implementing a MapType to act as a base map type can be a time-consuming and laborious >task. The API provides a special class that implements the MapType interface for the most >common map types: map types that consist of tiles made up of single image files.
>
> This class, the ImageMapType class, is constructed using an ImageMapTypeOptions object specification defining the following required properties:
>
> - tileSize (required) specifies the size of the tile (of type google.maps.Size). >Sizes must be rectangular though they need not be square.
> - getTileUrl (required) specifies the function, usually provided as an inline >function literal, to handle selection of the proper image tile based on supplied world >coordinates and zoom level.

Comment: FYI, Mike Williams has a nice tutorial on custom maps: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/custommap.htm

Comment: And also FYI, I wrote a blog post on how to speed up map tile generation: http://blog.webfoot.com/2013/03/12/optimizing-map-tile-generation/