# How to make a GoogleMaps-like Navigation in JavaScript or GWT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, gwt

I want to implement an application that uses a navigation similar to what is implemented form google maps.

The user should navigate on a window which dimensions are far bigger than his browser dimensions.

Navigation should be done by:

- mouse down and mouse move to move the window position
- mouse wheel up/down to zoom in/out
- navigation elements at the top left corner

I want to show html elements on the window. It is also important that when you scroll to the edges of the content on the window, the new content have to be loaded.

The image below shows an example:

[image]

**Is there a framework, a JavaScript library, a JQuery library or a GWT library to achieve that? How can I implement this?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079862/can-i-use-the-google-maps-api-to-display-a-custom-map

Comment: @HamzaKubba is there another possibility than using the google api?

Comment: this is not suitable for every page, but if you use SVG there is SVG pan which my team used quite successfully to implement a family tree. https://code.google.com/p/svgpan/ maybe it helps.

Comment: @awaigand I have a bunch of html elements that I want to display as you can see in the image I posted. I do not need svg. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: How about this http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-For-Panning-Zooming-Any-Elements-panzoom.html it allows you to pan and zoom any HTML Element (e.g. divs) and you can bind the zooms to certain buttons.

Comment: @awaigand that looks good, but how do I load the new content when moving to the borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve that behavior with pure javascript/css, the concept is known as "scrollable divs", you need two overlapping divs, the one on top is smaller than the one in the background. The one on top acts like a window and the div at the background is the one which is actually moving using the top/left or bottom/right properties.

Here is a popular script called sprymap.js, I would link to the original source but it looks like somebody forgot to renew a domain, [look at the live demo](http://www.spidersoft.com.au/demo/sprymap/):

```
/*
<beginLegalBanter>
The MIT License (MIT)
Copyright (c) 2011 Charlie Andrews
Small fixes made by Slawomir Jasinski - now is working on IE

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
</endLegalBanter>

Usage:
var map = new SpryMap({
   // The ID of the element being transformed into a map
   id : "",
   // The width of the map (in px)
   width: 800,
   // The height of the map (in px)
   height: 800,
   // The X value of the starting map position
   startX: 0,
   // The Y value of the starting map position
   startY: 0,
   // Boolean true if the map should animate to a stop
   scrolling: true,
   // The time (in ms) that the above scrolling lasts
   scrollTime: 300,
   // Boolean true if the map disallows moving past its edges
   lockEdges: true,
   // The CSS class attached to the wrapping map div
   cssClass: ""
   // The cursor CSS style rule to apply when the mouse hovers the map
   hoverCursor: "auto"
   // The cursor CSS style rule to apply when the mouse is dragged on the map
   dragCursor: "[closed hand cursor]"
});
*/
function SpryMap(param) {
    /**
     * Name:        MoveMap()
     * Description: Function that moves the map to a given X and Y offset.
     *              Note that the function takes into account locked edges in the
     *              map.
     * Parameters:  x - The new x offset of the map
     *              y - The new y offset of the map
     */
    function MoveMap(x, y) {
        var newX = x, newY = y;
        if(m.lockEdges) {
            var rightEdge = -m.map.offsetWidth + m.viewingBox.offsetWidth,
                topEdge = -m.map.offsetHeight + m.viewingBox.offsetHeight;
            newX = newX < rightEdge ? rightEdge : newX;
            newY = newY < topEdge ? topEdge : newY;
            newX = newX > 0 ? 0 : newX;
            newY = newY > 0 ? 0 : newY;
        }
        m.map.style.left = newX + "px";
        m.map.style.top = newY + "px";
    }

    /**
     * Name:        AddListener()
     * Description: Adds an event listener to the specified element.
     * Parameters:  element - The element for which the listener is being added
     *              event - The event for which the listener is being added
     *              f - The function being called each time that the event occurs
     */
    function AddListener(element, event, f) {
        if(element.attachEvent) {
            element["e" + event + f] = f;
            element[event + f] = function () {
                element["e" + event + f](window.event)
            };
            element.attachEvent("on" + event, element[event + f])
        } else element.addEventListener(event, f, false)
    }

    function Coordinate(startX, startY) {
        this.x = startX;
        this.y = startY;
    }

    var m = this;
    m.map = document.getElementById(param.id);
    m.width = typeof param.width == "undefined" ? 800 : param.width;
    m.height = typeof param.height == "undefined" ? 800 : param.height;
    m.scrolling = typeof param.scrolling == "undefined" ? true : param.scrolling;
    m.hoverCursor = param.hoverCursor || "auto";    // If you prefer, the "open hand" style is: "url(data:image/vnd.microsoft.icon;base64,AAACAAEAICACAAgACAAwAQAAFgAAACgAAAAgAAAAQAAAAAEAAQAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8AAAA/AAAAfwAAAP+AAAH/gAAB/8AAA//AAAd/wAAGf+AAAH9gAADbYAAA2yAAAZsAAAGbAAAAGAAAAAAAAA//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////gH///4B///8Af//+AD///AA///wAH//4AB//8AAf//AAD//5AA///gAP//4AD//8AF///AB///5A////5///8=), default"
    m.dragCursor = param.dragCursor || "url(data:image/vnd.microsoft.icon;base64,AAACAAEAICACAAcABQAwAQAAFgAAACgAAAAgAAAAQAAAAAEAAQAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAA////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8AAAA/AAAAfwAAAP+AAAH/gAAB/8AAAH/AAAB/wAAA/0AAANsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////gH///4B///8Af//+AD///AA///wAH//+AB///wAf//4AH//+AD///yT/////////////////////////////8=), default";
    m.scrollTime = typeof param.scrollTime == "undefined" ? 300 : param.scrollTime;
    m.lockEdges = typeof param.lockEdges == "undefined" ? true : param.lockEdges;
    m.viewingBox = document.createElement("div");
    if (typeof param.cssClass != "undefined") m.viewingBox.className = param.cssClass;
    m.viewingBox.style.cursor = m.hoverCursor;
    m.mousePosition = new Coordinate;
    m.mouseLocations = [];
    m.velocity = new Coordinate;
    m.mouseDown = false;
    m.timerId = -1;
    m.timerCount = 0;
    m.map.parentNode.replaceChild(m.viewingBox, m.map);
    m.viewingBox.appendChild(m.map);
    m.viewingBox.style.overflow = "hidden";
    m.viewingBox.style.width = m.width + "px";
    m.viewingBox.style.height = m.height + "px";
    m.viewingBox.style.position = "relative";
    m.map.style.position = "absolute";
    MoveMap(typeof param.startX == "undefined" ? 0 : -param.startX, typeof param.startY == "undefined" ? 0 : -param.startY);

    /**
     * Name:        MouseMove()
     * Description: Function called every time that the mouse moves
     */
    var MouseMove = function (b) {
        var e = b.clientX - m.mousePosition.x + parseInt(m.map.style.left),
            d = b.clientY - m.mousePosition.y + parseInt(m.map.style.top);
        MoveMap(e, d);
        m.mousePosition.x = b.clientX;
        m.mousePosition.y = b.clientY
    };

    /**
     * Name:        OnScrollTimer()
     * Description: Function called every time that the scroll timer fires
     */
    var OnScrollTimer = function () {
        if(m.mouseDown) {
            // Keep track of where the latest mouse location is
            m.mouseLocations.unshift(new Coordinate(m.mousePosition.x,
                                                    m.mousePosition.y));

            // Make sure that we're only keeping track of the last 10 mouse
            // clicks (just for efficiency)
            if(m.mouseLocations.length > 10)
                m.mouseLocations.pop();
        } else {

            var totalTics = m.scrollTime / 20;

            var fractionRemaining = (totalTics - m.timerCount) / totalTics;

            var xVelocity = m.velocity.x * fractionRemaining;
            var yVelocity = m.velocity.y * fractionRemaining;

            MoveMap(-xVelocity + parseInt(m.map.style.left),
                    -yVelocity + parseInt(m.map.style.top));

            // Only scroll for 20 calls of this function
            if(m.timerCount == totalTics) {
                clearInterval(m.timerId);
                m.timerId = -1
            }

            ++m.timerCount;
        }
    };

    /**
     * mousedown event handler
     */
    AddListener(m.viewingBox, "mousedown", function (e) {
        m.viewingBox.style.cursor = m.dragCursor;

        // Save the current mouse position so we can later find how far the
        // mouse has moved in order to scroll that distance
        m.mousePosition.x = e.clientX;
        m.mousePosition.y = e.clientY;

        // Start paying attention to when the mouse moves
        AddListener(document, "mousemove", MouseMove);
        m.mouseDown = true;

        // If the map is set to continue scrolling after the mouse is released,
        // start a timer for that animation
        if(m.scrolling) {
            m.timerCount = 0;

            if(m.timerId != 0)
            {
                clearInterval(m.timerId);
                m.timerId = 0;
            }

            m.timerId = setInterval(OnScrollTimer, 20);
        }

        event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    });

    /**
     * mouseup event handler
     */
    AddListener(document, "mouseup", function () {
        if(m.mouseDown) {
            var handler = MouseMove;
            if(document.detachEvent) {
                document.detachEvent("onmousemove", document["mousemove" + handler]);
                document["mousemove" + handler] = null;
            } else {
                document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handler, false);
            }

            m.mouseDown = false;

            if(m.mouseLocations.length > 0) {
                var clickCount = m.mouseLocations.length;
                m.velocity.x = (m.mouseLocations[clickCount - 1].x - m.mouseLocations[0].x) / clickCount;
                m.velocity.y = (m.mouseLocations[clickCount - 1].y - m.mouseLocations[0].y) / clickCount;
                m.mouseLocations.length = 0;
            }
        }

        m.viewingBox.style.cursor = m.hoverCursor;
    });
};
```

Comment: how do you manage to load content that is not on the screen and will be on the screen when the user scrolls towards it?

Comment: ahh you could make your own coordinate system, preferably pixel based,  calculate your bounding box( what you are going to see) and in the MoveMap function check if the new coordinates are within your bounding box, if not redraw everything starting in the new coordinates, or you can also extend your bounding box(using more memory).

Comment: is there a plugin for that?

Comment: mm I don't think so, since navigating dynamically allocated html would need more knowledge about the information itself, and a one fits all solution would have a poor performance in most cases.

Comment: How can I detect if I have to load new content?

Comment: Like I said you need a coordinate system(let's use pixels), also you need to store the position of everything and the bounding box of the current state of the map, for example let's assume that your starting bounding box is min-X:0,min-Y:0,max-X:800, max-Y:800. In the MoveMap function you can detect new coordinates, when you are near the borders (example x:0, y:400), you would want to move your bounding box 400px(half-width) on the x axis to min-X:-400,min-Y:0,max-X:400, max-Y:800.